# table column headers does not sort the data

Tags: c#, sorting, jquery-jtable

I'm a fairly junior C# developer so please excuse me if this is very easy. I am trying to sort the data in `ASC` and `DESC` order when hit the table column headers, but for some reason it's not doing it.

Here's the sorting code for your inspection:

```
if (sorting != null)
                {
                    if (sorting.Equals("TrackID ASC"))
                    {
                        daa.OrderBy(p => p.TrackID);
                    }
                    else if (sorting.Equals("TrackID DESC"))
                    {
                        daa.OrderByDescending(p => p.TrackID);
                    }
                    if (sorting.Equals("TrackName ASC"))
                    {
                        daa.OrderBy(p => p.TrackName);
                    }
                    else if (sorting.Equals("TrackName DESC"))
                    {
                        daa.OrderByDescending(p => p.TrackName);
                    }
                    else if (sorting.Equals("DateTimes ASC"))
                    {
                        daa.OrderBy(p => p.Date);
                    }
                    else if (sorting.Equals("DateTimes DESC"))
                    {
                        daa.OrderByDescending(p => p.Date);
                    }
                    else if (sorting.Equals("ArtistName ASC"))
                    {
                        daa.OrderBy(p => p.ArtistName);
                    }
                    else if (sorting.Equals("ArtistName DESC"))
                    {
                        daa.OrderByDescending(p => p.ArtistName);
                    }
                    else if (sorting.Equals("Times ASC"))
                    {
                        daa.OrderBy(p => p.Times);
                    }
                    else if (sorting.Equals("Times DESC"))
                    {
                        daa.OrderByDescending(p => p.Times);
                    }
                }
```

Can someone please explain why it's not working and how do I work around and achieve it to sort the data in `ASC` and `DESC` order?

Any help would be great :) thanks

Comment: @chandreshpatel yes I did and couldn't find anything that could explain it or resolve my issue, hence I had a look here to before posting my question. I am not trying to sort the data in a gridview. I am using jQuery jTable as mentioned above.

Comment: Did you debug the list puting break point? Is it sorting or not. If daa is a IEnumerable type then it will definaltly sort.

Comment: @chandreshpatel thanks for that.. this is what `daa` is `List<TopPlayed> daa = new List<TopPlayed>();` it's not `IEnumerable type`. Can I convert it to `IEnumerable` from `List`? Thanks again :)

Comment: List allready implement IEnumerable so what you have done is correct. may be only you are not updating your control. just put break point and check.

Comment: @chandreshpatel thanks, then it should `sort` the column headers shouldn't it? Do you know what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly methods "OrderBy" and "OrderByDescending" don't sort object that called them directly. Instead they return IOrderedEnumerable< object> collection so you need to either sort your daa collection yourself using IOrderedEnumerable as reference, or create your collection type from IOrderedEnumerable and assing it to daa. And of course refresh ui.

Comment: thanks for your answer, made a lot of sense now. Let me try what you suggested and thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (sorting != null)
                {
                    if (sorting.Equals("TrackID ASC"))
                    {
                       daa = daa.OrderBy(p => p.TrackID).ToList();
                    }
                    else if (sorting.Equals("TrackID DESC"))
                    {
                      daa =  daa.OrderByDescending(p => p.TrackID).ToList();
                    }
                    if (sorting.Equals("TrackName ASC"))
                    {
                     daa =   daa.OrderBy(p => p.TrackName).ToList();
                    }
                    else if (sorting.Equals("TrackName DESC"))
                    {
                      daa =  daa.OrderByDescending(p => p.TrackName).ToList();
                    }
                    else if (sorting.Equals("DateTimes ASC"))
                    {
                       daa = daa.OrderBy(p => p.Date).ToList();
                    }
                    else if (sorting.Equals("DateTimes DESC"))
                    {
                      daa =  daa.OrderByDescending(p => p.Date).ToList();
                    }
                    else if (sorting.Equals("ArtistName ASC"))
                    {
                       daa = daa.OrderBy(p => p.ArtistName).ToList();
                    }
                    else if (sorting.Equals("ArtistName DESC"))
                    {
                      daa =  daa.OrderByDescending(p => p.ArtistName).ToList();
                    }
                    else if (sorting.Equals("Times ASC"))
                    {
                      daa =  daa.OrderBy(p => p.Times).ToList();
                    }
                    else if (sorting.Equals("Times DESC"))
                    {
                      daa =  daa.OrderByDescending(p => p.Times).ToList();
                    }
                }
```

try this also once.

Comment: thanks for that :) - Your fix seemed to be the closet but it didn't work. I got this error `cannot implicitly convert type System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<TopPlayed> to System.Collections.Generic.List<TopPlayed>`. Did exactly what you suggested.. any way to convert this? thanks again :)

Comment: thanks again :) it didn't work :( are we missing something major here?

Comment: This will sort for sure. I don't know what wrong you are doing you have to debug and try.

Comment: that's great man.. appreciate your help soo far! I'll check whats happening in depth by debugging it; atleast this `sorting` query was right. thanks man